# Sending email though local proxy server

Tags: .net, email, c#-4.0, proxy, smtpclient

I am developing an application to attache files from my hard driver and email to specific email address. It is working properly when i use my personal Internet Connection. But there is a problem when i use my university internet connection. That is connected through a local proxy server.
This is the function that I implemented to send emails. How to detect local proxy server automatically when sending emails.

```
 public static void SendAttachedEmail()
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("FromEmail@gmail.com");
            MailAddress toAddress = new MailAddress("ToEmail@gmail.com");
            mail.From = fromAddress;
            mail.To.Add(toAddress);
            mail.Subject = "Ledger Files";
            mail.Body = "HP-PC";
            Attachment file;
            file = new Attachment(path + filename);
            mail.Attachments.Add(file);
            client.Port = 587;                
            NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("FromEmail@gmail.com", "FromEmailPassword");
            client.Credentials = credentials;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Send(mail);
            Console.WriteLine("Sending Successful : " + filename);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether or not you can actually access the SMTP servers from university (Have you tried logging into your gmail account/hotmail account and actually sending something as an attachment? It's possible it could be blocked.

Comment: Yes. I can log my email through university internet line. before that, i have to change the proxy settings in Control panel. To download something through Internet Download Manager i have to configure proxy settings in Internet download manager. Sending email has not been blocked in this internet line.